# page can not be displayed niether in explorer nor in chrome

Tags: php

I am developing a php project,in which everytime when I
 run(http://localhost/CoffeeWebsite/index.php), it run perfectly, but
 when I tried today morning , it says "page cannot displayed", this is
 not the internet problem, because other sites opens perfectly, even I
 post this question from the same internet connection, what should be
 the issue?

Comment: Your local server has stopped. You need to restart it.

Comment: have you tried starting/ restarting your local host, i.e., WAMP or XAMPP or..?

Answer (score 0):

Start your xampp/wamp or what ever you have And start apache service or all services.